# Free program to sync folder with FTP?

Tags: sync, ftp

My business partner has a lot of files that he needs to sync to our website's private folder so that I can download the changes. We really need a good tool that can keep these sync'd. I have tried a few solutions, but none seem to work very well.

Is there a program that you used to do this that you found works well (would prefer an easy solution to setup as he is not very tech savvy)?

Comment: Which operating system(s)?

Comment: We are both on Windows (Vista 64-bit for me, I think he is still on XP SP3). The site is Linux

Comment: Have you considered using a shared DropBox?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use SyncBack, the free version supports basic ftp

features at:
http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/compare.html

Comment: That looks closer to what I was looking for. I will give it a try and let you know (giving you the +1 already)

Comment: Works great. Thanks! Will probably end up getting the pro-mode as well.

Comment: +1 for SyncBack, I used to use it all the time. You can also try IQBox FTP Client. It's open-source and free. I'm the lead developer.
https://www.iqstorage.com/iqbox.php

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you are the only one who needs access to those files and they don't actually have to be on the webserver (you are just using it for convenience sake)? If that is the case, LiveMesh (MS Product) would be the way to go. Create 2 folders, one with your name and one with his and you will be able to edit approve, track changes, etc. It also allows you to access the files when your not at your pc via a virtual desktop.

The service gives you a few gb of space as well (free obviously).

Comment: thanks, but we are talking about 20-30gb at some times. Will keep in mind for future use though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you refer to a business -- there is a commercial service [**SugarSync**](https://www.sugarsync.com/)
It has a **two-point, 2GB free edition** and a **15-day free trial**.

There will be quite a few free techniques (including a [Gmail Filesystem](http://richard.jones.name/google-hacks/gmail-filesystem/gmail-filesystem.html)).
But, do you want to get into them when you have a business to look after?

Comment: thanks, but I do not want to have these files on anybody's file system but our own. I would prefer a solution that works with our own server. I apologize if I did not make that clear. Basically like windows file sync, but will work with FTP protocol.

Comment: @IPX, Well, you could still encrypt the files shared.

Comment: But, if you run the site, a `CVS` or `git` solution should be good.

Comment: `FTP` will need a lot of wrap-up...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/
offrers HFS ~ Http File Server

Answer (score 0):

http://www.manyfish.co.uk/sitecopy/ is amazing (set it up once, sync all with single command-line command, very rich system for file exclusions). 
Sometimes it sucks (unable to cope with relative links on server - exits on finding them :( ), but it is still the easiest way to push website changes.