# Mirror local with FTP

Tags: windows, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free program to sync folder with FTP?](https://superuser.com/questions/25544/free-program-to-sync-folder-with-ftp)

I'm looking for a program for Windows that will allow me to easily mirror select files and directories on my local computer with an FTP server and vice versa.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/25544/free-program-to-sync-folder-with-ftp and http://superuser.com/questions/48782/keep-ftp-folder-syncd-with-windows-folder.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is another option using winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_synchronize)

It is a decent FTP/SFTP client as well

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [FTPSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftpsync/). It's a [Perl](http://perl.org) script that does exactly what you need.