# Automatically sync files to FTP Server

Tags: sync, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free program to sync folder with FTP?](https://superuser.com/questions/25544/free-program-to-sync-folder-with-ftp)

I'm frequently edit many files at home, then go to school and edit those same files.

I'm getting tired of deleting everything on my local directory, then copy everything from my server to that directory, and then do the same when I'm at school.

I recently started using WinSCP to sync the folders, but I want it even easier (maybe I'm just greedy).

I'm looking for a program that will detect changes to a remote/local directory. If there is a change, it will sync the changes to the other computer. (If the change was local, it syncs to my server. If the server is different than the local directory, it syncs back).

I think it's alright if I have to use WinSCP to sync server changes back, but I would really like a program that can at least sync local changes to the server.

Does anyone know of a program that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Novell has a program called NetDrive which does this quite well, and it also maps a drive letter locally for you to the FTP server (something Novell's developers have a great deal of talent in due to the work they did with the Novell Client software over the years all the way back from DOS up to 32/64-bit Windows 7 currently).

Unfortunately getting your hands on it can be a little bit tricky -- they don't have a direct download for it anymore, but it is included with Support Pack 5 for NetWare 6 as part of the iFolder product.  What you can do is get this service pack file, extract it using 7-Zip if you don't have ARJ (it's self-extracting, or you can rename the .exe to .arj and extract it that way), then find NetDrive in there somewhere.  Here's a forum conversation where someone confirms that it is included with that Support Pack update:

Re: Ne[w]er version of NetDrive?
  http://forums.novell.com/novell-product-support-forums/ifolder/151911-never-version-netdrive-post633790.html

If this does work well for you, I recommend that you contact Novell to find out if there are any licensing costs.

Comment: I'll look into that. However, do you think it might be better to map a network drive to a FTP location, and then sync folders that way?

Comment: If you have the software to do it, then it may be.  The very best of course is to use "rsync" since it is designed for synchronization in a way that you can get the most out of your bandwidth:  http://rsync.samba.org/

Comment: If I had to synchronize over network drive letters, I'd use SMB (the Windows file sharing stuff) over OpenVPN because FTP tends to have a lot of overhead when dealing with a large number of files (SMB has overhead too, but much less as I understand it):  http://www.openvpn.net/